# How do I make a content control accessible to multiple WPF windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a WPF application that uses multiple windows. I have a ContentControl defined for one window, and I would like to be able to use it in the other windows as well.

Right now, my Content Control is defined in the xaml file for one of my windows.

How should I define this content control so that I may access it from all the other windows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it into a usercontrol.

In Blend it's as easy as selected the control, right clicking and selecting "make into usercontrol" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare it public by using the `x:FieldModifier` attribute:

```
<ContentControl Name="myControl" x:FieldModifier="Public">
...
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing that... instead, you should expose the content itself, not the `ContentControl`. You can expose it through a public property, or pass it as a constructor parameter to other windows

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, what do you mean by expose?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
I am not sure what you mean by "expose through a public property." I have moved the content control to the App.xaml, but my windows do not recognize it. I define it as:
<ContentControl x:Key="timeout" Name="TicketContent"...../>
In my window, I am trying to do something like this:
App.TicketContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
However, the program claims there is no such thing as TicketContent in App.

Comment: The only things you can declare in App.xaml are resources. Controls are *not* resources. Declare the control in the UI where it should be displayed, and access it from there. Anyway, if you just want to control the visibility, why don't you use a binding ? Writing WPF apps without taking advantage of data binding is like trying to drive your car with someone pushing behind instead of starting the engine...

Comment: So then do I need to put the code for the Control Content into the xaml file for each window where I want it to be displayed?

Comment: You can't display the same control in multiple windows. Each window must have its own instance of the control. That's why I said you shouldn't try to share the control itself between the windows: you should only share the content that is displayed in the control